# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1

Tags: exception

https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1483

I've tried the solution given at the above site but it still throws the same exception.

```
public class QueryBrowserDao extends MySQL5Dialect{

public QueryBrowserDao(){
    super();
    registerHibernateType( Types.LONGVARCHAR, Hibernate.TEXT.getName() );

}
```

F1 F1 F1...

Answer (score 0):

Just to help anyone else with the same problem...

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding to the SQLQuery object, type information of the conflictive field:

```
SQLQuery sqlQuery = getSession().createSQLQuery("select t.* from `track` t");
sqlQuery.addScalar("t.name", Hibernate.STRING);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **addScalar()**.

For example:

```
((SQLQuery) ((HibernateQuery) query).getHibernateQuery())
            .addScalar("column1", new LongType())
            .addScalar("column2", new IntegerType())
            .addScalar("column3", new StringType());
```